# Can I instantiate a named stateless bean?

Tags: javabeans, cdi, managed, jta, stateless

I'm migrating a big application to CDI with JPA.
Before I can change all code, I need to know if following pattern will work. This will allow me to migrate the application partially.

My Managed Bean:

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class LanguageBoundary implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    LanguageService languageService;

    @Inject
    CrudService crudService;

    public LanguageEntity findById(Long id) {
        return crudService.find(LanguageEntity.class, id);
    }
```

...

***Can I use in any other class:***

```
// Methods: DAO - Used by original deprecated parent wrapper class
public LanguageEntity findByIdImpl(Id id) {

    LanguageBoundary lb = new LanguageBoundary();
    return lb.findById(id.getValue());
}
```

Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do something like this, you need to get a reference to the object.  You can do this using CDI.  In CDI 1.1 you can get the CDI utility class.  In CDI 1.0 you can get a reference to the bean manager using JNDI to do the equivalent.  Look at this code for reference: https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L98

I'm curious why you're using `@Named`.  Are you planning to reference the EJB directly in your UI?

Comment: I am as curious as John is. '@Named' declares a CDI bean visible to the web pages via EL, where '@Stateless' declares an EJB container bean. Separation of concerns does not encourage mixing both. Plus, it is not a good practice to expose EJB components to the UI layer.

Answer (score 4):

If you instantiate it, the bean wouldn´t be managed by the container, so it´s probably not what you want. Instead, you should inject it with `@Inject`